# What is the term for a Monarchy with only a King or a Queen, but not both?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, terminology

A typical Monarchy can have a king, queen, or both.  What is the term for, like the current British Monarchy, having only one of a king or a queen <strike>in power</strike>?  Surely there is a term that distinguishes that situation from one where there is a King *and* Queen sitting.

To clarify: The answer to the question is a term, not a historical or political definition.  The usage of the term I am looking for would be to illustrate needing to have both a king and a queen, not just one or the other.

In other words: what is the common nomenclature for having a king, or a queen, but not having both?  It is irrelevant who has the power.  What matters is that the king doesn't have a queen.

Comment: A queen, where there is a king, has no power. It's still a monarchy. The exception was the joint "monarchy" of William III and Mary II, where they were both sovereign. I guess that would be a *joint sovereignty* rather than a monarchy.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is rooted in a misunderstanding about the nature of a system of government.

Comment: Actually, a typical monarchy can not have just a queen. It is fairly exceptional (and usually recent) as far as monarchies go, that a queen could actually reign. Traditionally, the queen was only the king's wife, with no specific power (other than being rich and sleeping with the boss...)

Comment: As @ermanen’s answer implies, the term you are looking for is technically _monarchy_, which implies that there is only _one_ ruler—the case in nearly all modern monarchies, even if there is both a king and a queen.

Comment: Unfortunately your statement about the British monarchy is incorrect. We just didn't want Phil the Greek as king.

Comment: Your edit has actually made things worse. Are you looking for the term for a system that has one ruler, either a king or a queen? That's what the title asks, and the answer is *Monarchy*. Or are you asking about a hypothetical (and unworkable) system that requires a king and a queen, equal in power, at all times? If so, there is no normal term, though various possibilties could be used.

Comment: @oerkelens That's not correct. If a woman inherits the throne from her parents, she is the monarch, she is called the queen and her husband, if she has one, has no specific power and is not called king. If a man inherits the throne from his parents, he is the monarch, he is called the king and his wife, if she has one, has no specific power but is called queen. This is the case in at least the UK, the Netherlands, Sweden and Imperial Russia.

Comment: Yes, and those are exceptions. Actually, Russia was not a monarchy, but OK. Traditionally, a woman simply _could_ not inherit the title. However, in some cases they ran out of male heirs and changed the rules to allow women on the throne.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, I’m not sure about the Netherlands, but both Denmark and Sweden have changed their constitutions fairly recently (Denmark in 1953, Sweden in 1980) to move away from agnatic primogeniture (Denmark first to male-preference primogeniture, and then in 2009 joining Sweden in absolute primogeniture). Before that, a woman simply _could not_ inherit the throne, even if she was the only heir. With a few notable exceptions (at least three of them in the UK), having a ruling queen has indeed been a not-very-common exception in monarchies worldwide until well into the 20th century.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Margaret (queen regnant of Denmark, 1387-1412) and Ulrica Eleanor (queen regnant of Sweden, 1718-20) and others are counterexamples to your claim that it was impossible for women to inherit either throne until the 20th century.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, Margaret I was never queen of Denmark. Her title was _fuldmægtig frue og husbond og det ganske rige Danmarks formynder_ (Sovereign Lady and Husband and Guardian to All the Kingdom of Denmark). Upon her father’s death, she specifically _did not_ inherit the throne which (after some intrigues) passed her and went to her son, the former king’s grandson. Ulrica Eleanor was only actually queen by inheritance in name for about a month (and mostly by her own brash claim)—after that, she, like Margaret, was _elected_ queen regnant.

Comment: Please do not raise issues of editorial policy by editing your question. You can do it in comment, or else post it as a separate question on the English Meta site instead of the main site.

Answer (score 13):

> While most monarchs have been male, many female monarchs also have reigned in history; the term **queen regnant** refers to a ruling monarch, while a **queen consort** refers to the wife of a reigning king.
>
> Most states only have a single person acting as monarch at any given time, although two monarchs have ruled simultaneously in some countries, a situation known as **diarchy**.

<sub>~Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monarchy</sub>

---

To clarify further:

> A **monarch** is a supreme or absolute head of a state government, either in reality or symbolically.
>
> Such a government is known as a monarchy. A monarch typically either inherits sovereignty (often referred to as the throne) by birth or is elected monarch and typically rules for life or until abdication.
>
> Monarchs have various titles — king or queen, prince or princess (e.g., Sovereign Prince of Monaco), emperor or empress (e.g., Emperor of Japan, Emperor of India), archduke, duke or grand duke (e.g., Grand Duke of Luxembourg).
>
> **Prince is sometimes used as a generic term to describe any monarch regardless of title, especially in older texts.**

<sub>~Source:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monarch</sub>

Answer (score 5):

A "monarchy," by definition, is a "one person" rule. (Mono= one, archy=rule). In English history, there was the joint rule of "William and Mary" cited by others, but that was the exception, not the rule.

The confusion may arise from the fact that most "monarchs" have spouses. These spouses are referred to as "consorts" and are often given "equivalent" titles that make it seem that they are "co-rulers," but they're not.

A male monarch is called a king. His wife is usually referred to as a "queen," but she would be a "queen consort," that is the "wife of a king," not the other type of queen referred to below.

Queen Elizabeth II (and I) is a type of "queen," known as a queen **regnant,** or reigning queen. She inherited the job from her father, not a "consortship" from her husband. Her husband, Philip of Greece, is known as Prince Philip, or the Prince Consort. He is an English "prince" by virtue of being a "spouse," not descended from royalty like Elizabeth.

Comment: As it happens, he was born Prince Philip. He's the grandson of King George I of Greece.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Changed that to English Prince. Ok, he was a Greek prince as well.

Answer (score 4):

*Monarchy* comes from the Greek for 'one ruler'. So all monarchies have either a king or a queen in power; though the ruler's spouse may be called 'queen' or 'prince consort', the title does not grant equality. If it did, the system would no longer be a monarchy: possibly, as mentioned above, a diarchy.

(Note for historical pedants: though Philip of Spain thought that marrying Mary Tudor made him King of England, he discovered he was mistaken. And though William and Mary were later joint sovereigns, that was a unique situation, where Parliament had tired of the strict monarchical system and issued a carefully worded invitation.)

Comment: I don't think it had to do with "tired of the strict monarchical system." More likely it was a result of William's Dutch army representing the balance of power in an otherwise English "civil war" between Mary II and her father James II.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a particular term for a monarchy in this situation because there's no difference as to who is ruling. It's just a question of what title is granted to the spouse of the monarch.

In the United Kingdom and its predecessors (at least England), the title granted to the husband of a reigning Queen has never been King. King William III was the husband of the reigning Queen Mary II, but he wasn't King simply because of that, he was King because he was also co-ruler.

However, the title of the wife of a king is Queen. If Queen Elizabeth II were a man then she'd be King Elizabeth II, and the title of that king's wife would (generally) be Queen.

I say "generally" because Prince Charles's wife Camilla is expected not to take the title Queen should he be king. She is currently styled Duchess of Cornwall (he is the Duke of Cornwall) but not Princess of Wales (which she would be entitled to, but she and others felt the association of the title with Diana to be too strong).

So I think there's a false assumption in your question, which is that there are monarchies that "need to have both a king and a queen". If that happens anywhere it isn't the typical case. So it's not a question of needing a queen vs. not needing one, it's a case of the monarch happening to be both male and married, or not.

Who knows, maybe the next difficult question for the royal protocol officers will be how to style the husband of a reigning king, or the wife of a reigning queen ;-)

Comment: That's likely to be *Prince Consort* in the first case (precedent: Philip Duke of Edinburgh, husband of a monarch) and by corollary *Princess Consort* in the second. A rather more pressing question will be what to call Queen Camilla if she is denied the title "Queen". HRH The Princess Consort has been suggested there, too.

Answer (score -2):

why not an "Exclusive Monarchy"